# Migrating Document libraries to new location (and new subsite) while retaining internal ID's

Tags: powershell, migration, import, export

I'm currently using `SPExportSettings` and `SPImportSettings` to migrate some content from an old 2007 environment.

The below code is all working fine, as designed, but not as I'd like. My document libraries need to retain their internal ID's after the migration.

Because I have `RetainObjectIdentity = $true` on the import, that seems to keep the libraries URL structure in tact, so it ignores my `$_destWebUrl`, for where to import to (they originate in the rootweb so they are being deployed to the new rootweb).

If I set `RetainObjectIdentity = $false`, then it's imported to the subsite as I'd like, but the ID's are all gone.

Desired Source: http://sharepoint/MigrationSource

Desired Target: http://sharepoint/MigrationTarget/SUBSITE

Relevant export code:

```
$settings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExportSettings
$settings.SiteUrl = $_sourceSite
$settings.ExportMethod = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExportMethodType]::ExportAll
$settings.IncludeSecurity = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPIncludeSecurity]::All
$settings.FileLocation = $_fileLocation
$settings.FileCompression = $true
$settings.BaseFileName = $_fileName
$settings.OverwriteExistingDataFile = $true
$settings.IncludeVersions = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPIncludeVersions]::All
```

....snip

```
foreach ($obj in $_exportObjs)
{
    # Create a new SPExportObject which contains the content to be exported
    $exportObject = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExportObject
    $exportObject.IncludeDescendants = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPIncludeDescendants]::All
    $exportObject.Type = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentObjectType]::List
    $exportObject.Id = $_spweb.Lists.TryGetList($obj).ID
    $settings.ExportObjects.Add($exportObject)
    Write-Host `t`t$obj" has been added"
}
```

And import code:

```
$settings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportSettings
$settings.SiteUrl = $_destSiteUrl
$settings.WebUrl = $_destWebUrl
$settings.FileLocation = $_fileLocation
$settings.BaseFileName = $_fileName
$settings.FileCompression = $true
$settings.RetainObjectIdentity = $true
$settings.UserInfoDateTime = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportUserInfoDateTimeOption]::ImportAll
```

If there is no way around this issue, is there a way to move a document library, within a site collection, while retaining all internal ID's?

Comment: I'll noodle on this a bit, but in the meantime can I ask why you want to retain the IDs?

Comment: I'm assisting in a migration on an asp.net app that is living in SharePoint. The original developers made it a requirement. They use the ID's, in some way, in their custom DB.

Comment: We might be able to get away with allowing the library ID's to change, and attempt to keep the ListItem ID's (if possible).

Comment: That's what the RetainObjectIdentity property does...retains the list item's GUID. As far as I know it does not retain the ID of the list/library.

Comment: I'm able to do either: 1) Migrate the entire library and list items, retain the ID's (but not in the desired location), or 2) Migrate the library to the desired location, but without the ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here after I've had some time to look at it. This is expected functionality. If a List/Library exists in the Root web, in order to keep its identity, it can only be imported into the root web of the target site.

Of course, if you choose NOT to retain identities, you can subscribe to the SPImport's events and set their parents.